# Error while installing Spring Boot Tool in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse

I am trying to install Spring boot Tool from Eclipse Marketplace.

While installing an error occurred as follows:

```
session context was:(profile=C__Users_ritik_eclipse_jee-2021-12_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 810cecf8ba271008.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 810cecf8ba271008.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 70b824d9a6b4ae29.
OK
```

[image: Screenshot]

I had uninstalled eclipse and then tried installing spring boot again received the same error as above.

Then i formatted the whole laptop and then tried received the same error.

Please help if anyone has come across such error.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Spring from here:
https://spring.io/tools

Select: Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse
This will download a .jar with Eclipse and Spring, execute him and run SpringToolSuite4.exe, you dont have to install Eclipse or have it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, resolved problem reinstalling Eclipse to 2023-03 (4.27.0) version.

Link to download: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2023-03/R/eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe

And add SpringBoot plugin from Eclipse Marketplace.